# Dynamically calculated Row height in Tables

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx

I am trying to dynamically allocate the height of rows in a table based upon a number, specifically the number of minutes that are devoted to a specific activity in a class lesson. The table represents the lesson plan which is broken up into parts, a large row indicates a longer activity, and a short row a short activity etc. I can see how to adjust the row height by using \[2em] at the end of the row, but I would rather calculate this value from item 1, since the row height should be proportional to the number of minutes in the activity, I also calculate a running total so that the teacher can easily when each part of the lesson starts, durring the hour, and that works fine.[image]

See the definitions for \R, I have been strugleing with this for a few days and not getting anywhere, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

% ----------------- my lesson customisations -------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcounter{LessonNumber}
\setcounter{LessonNumber}{0}

% The following command takes an integer minute value and returns it in hour:min format
\newcommand{\hourFormat}[1]{  0:{\pgfmathparse{int(#1/10)}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,10))}\pgfmathresult} }


% \hline % works before the \hourFormat


\newcommand{\rowHeight}[1]{  {\pgfmathparse{int(#1*0.4 + 0.5)}\pgfmathresult}  }


\def\R #1|#2|#3|#4 {\hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#1}   & #2 & #3 & #4  }%  <-- Works but not calculating the row height.
% \def\R #1|#2|#3|#4 {\hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#1}   & #2 & #3 &  #4[\rowHeight{#1}em] } <-- Calculates Row height, but does not effect the heigh, param not passed to tabular.
% \def\R #1|#2|#3|#4 {\hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#1}   & #2 & #3 &  #4\\[\rowHeight{#1}em] }%  <--- DOESNT WORK

% Keep track of the time/minutes in the lesson.
\newcounter{MinsIntoLesson}

\newcommand{\timelineheader}{ \textbf{Time} & \textbf{\mbox{Content}} & \textbf{Learning Activities} & \textbf{Resources} \\  \hline}
\newcommand{\timelinecolors}{ } % \rowcolors{2}{white}{cyan!25} }

%%%% Begining of the lesson 
\newcommand{\newlesson}[1]{ \addtocounter{LessonNumber}{1}\subsubsection{{Lesson \theLessonNumber} #1} }

\newenvironment{nulesson}[4]{       % #1 is the lesson title
      \newpage
      \addtocounter{LessonNumber}{1}
      \setcounter{MinsIntoLesson}{-60}

               \subsubsection{{Lesson \theLessonNumber} #1, #3} % \begin{flushright}#3\end{flushright}

At the end of this lesson students should be able to ... }{\newpage} % End of newenvironment 

% ---------------------------- Start of Document -----------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\begin{nulesson}{Unit overview and Review of Statistics}{Ch 4. Sec 4.}{SM1,SM2}{Unit overview and Review of Statistics}

% Lesson Time line planning
\begin{table}[h]
          \timelinecolors
          \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{c | L | L | L}
            \timelineheader
            \R 5  | \mbox{Introduction} | Students enter class, roll call and lesson goal displayed on projector  | Roll  \\[2em]
            \R 5  | Ted Talk | The teacher presents a short  Ted talk by Arthur Benjamin  |  www.ted.com \\[2em]
            \R 20 | Unit Overview  |Teacher led discussion reviewing the unit material | Overhead projector \\[10em]
            \R 25  | Review of statistical Measures | Formative assessment to assess the students abilities | Formative Assessment  \\[10em]
            \R 5  | Lesson Close | Lesson review and students tidy desks and leave class  |  \\[2em]
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{nulesson}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that I did was to add a `\rule[\dimexpr9pt-#1\hunits\relax]{0pt}{#1\hunits}` to the 1st column definition of `\R`, where `\hunits` was chosen to meet the overall height (time) constraints.  In this case, `\hunits` is set to 3.5 pt, meaning each minute of your lesson gets 3.5pt of vertical space.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

% ----------------- my lesson customisations -------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\newcounter{LessonNumber}
\setcounter{LessonNumber}{0}

% The following command takes an integer minute value and returns it in hour:min format
\newcommand{\hourFormat}[1]{  0:{\pgfmathparse{int(#1/10)}\pgfmathresult}{\pgfmathparse{int(mod(#1,10))}\pgfmathresult} }


% \hline % works before the \hourFormat


\newcommand{\rowHeight}[1]{  {\pgfmathparse{int(#1*0.4 + 0.5)}\pgfmathresult}  }

\newlength\hunits
\setlength\hunits{3.5pt}
\def\R #1|#2|#3|#4 {\hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#1}%
\rule[\dimexpr9pt-#1\hunits\relax]{0pt}{#1\hunits}   & #2 & #3 & #4  }%  <-- Works but not calculating the row height.
% \def\R #1|#2|#3|#4 {\hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#1}   & #2 & #3 &  #4[\rowHeight{#1}em] } <-- Calculates Row height, but does not effect the heigh, param not passed to tabular.
% \def\R #1|#2|#3|#4 {\hline \hourFormat{\theMinsIntoLesson}  \addtocounter{MinsIntoLesson}{#1}   & #2 & #3 &  #4\\[\rowHeight{#1}em] }%  <--- DOESNT WORK

% Keep track of the time/minutes in the lesson.
\newcounter{MinsIntoLesson}

\newcommand{\timelineheader}{ \textbf{Time} & \textbf{\mbox{Content}} & \textbf{Learning Activities} & \textbf{Resources} \\  \hline}
\newcommand{\timelinecolors}{ } % \rowcolors{2}{white}{cyan!25} }

%%%% Begining of the lesson 
\newcommand{\newlesson}[1]{ \addtocounter{LessonNumber}{1}\subsubsection{{Lesson \theLessonNumber} #1} }

\newenvironment{nulesson}[4]{       % #1 is the lesson title
      \newpage
      \addtocounter{LessonNumber}{1}
      \setcounter{MinsIntoLesson}{-60}

               \subsubsection{{Lesson \theLessonNumber} #1, #3} % \begin{flushright}#3\end{flushright}

At the end of this lesson students should be able to ... }{\newpage} % End of newenvironment 

% ---------------------------- Start of Document -----------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.5}
\begin{nulesson}{Unit overview and Review of Statistics}{Ch 4. Sec 4.}{SM1,SM2}{Unit overview and Review of Statistics}

% Lesson Time line planning
\begin{table}[h]
          \timelinecolors
          \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{c | L | L | L}
            \timelineheader
            \R 5  | \mbox{Introduction} | Students enter class, roll call and lesson goal displayed on projector  | Roll  \\
            \R 5  | Ted Talk | The teacher presents a short  Ted talk by Arthur Benjamin  |  www.ted.com \\
            \R 20 | Unit Overview  |Teacher led discussion reviewing the unit material | Overhead projector \\
            \R 25  | Review of statistical Measures | Formative assessment to assess the students abilities | Formative Assessment  \\
            \R 5  | Lesson Close | Lesson review and students tidy desks and leave class  |  \\
    \end{tabulary}
\end{table}
\end{nulesson}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that if a multiline cell like "Learning Activities" is too long, it could (and does) overwhelm the vertical height set by the rule.  I show this below by making the rule 1pt in width:

[image]

Comment: Thakns very much for that answer Steven, I have been struggleing with this problem all day, and my solution is very messy. I was also using rule once I figures out exactly what a rule was. I think it is probably fine or even better to have an overrun.

Comment: @MichaelTMckeon  Glad to help.  Welcome to the site!